# Android - Linkify.WEB_URLS dots clickable

Tags: android, linker, textview, clickable

I have a TextView that is a comment written by an user : (for e.g.)

Hello, I have a pet here.Can you adopt it? Please visit our website: www.example.com

I am doing:

```
Linkify.addLinks(holder.tvDescription, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

The problem is that in only some devices the DOT (here.Can) is making the word clickable. Though, in other devices it`s not being clickable (that should be correct).

The website is clickable (correct).

Comment: There is a space between here and can? if not, add it.

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I can't. Its a comment made by an user.